# How would one go around UI binding with Redux and React in mind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, react-router, redux

In modular OOP JavaScript, you can bind all of your event handlers in a single file.

**Example:**

```
bindActions: () => {
  elem.s.createGrid.addEventListener("click",() =>{
    bitIllustrator.updatedSettings();
    bitIllustrator.hideShow();
    bitIllustrator.resizeGrid();
    grid.createGridIllustrator();
  });
  elem.el.viewButton.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    cntrlView.removeTiles();
    cntrlView.addBackTiles();
  });
```

All events are packed into a single file, acting as a reference to files where you can find my function(s) in (Amongst other benefits based on the event type)

**Question:**

I was wondering what the best practice would be in React, with Redux in mind. I would prefer not to use React-Router, but will do so if it is something that makes sense in this particular instance.

**Current Implementation:**

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick} id="create_grid" type="button" className = "choose-size__form__button">Create Grid</button>

handleClick(){
    // this.refs.chooseSizeContainer;
    const container = document.getElementById("choose_size_container");
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
 ReactDOM.render(<ControlPanel/>, document.getElementById("header-container"));
 ReactDOM.render(<CodeBox/>, document.getElementById("code_box_container"));

 //need to put new elements that should be rendered here
}
```

Comment: This question is very broad. You really need to make an attempt yourself to re-write it in React. To get you started: Each view element should be its own React component. Each button click should fire an *action*. Your *reducers* change the state according to the action fired. Your React components will then re-render according to the new state.

Comment: David, thanks for your comment!  I have updated my question above with snippets of my current implementation. Thank you :)

Comment: You don't actually want to be un-mounting and re-mounting your components. Generally you only call `ReactDOM.render()` when you initialise your app. From that point, the view changes in response to changes in props and state. I recommend the Thinking in React tutorial. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Comment: Ok, so I should create another question as time goes on?

Comment: David, just one last question. If I am unmounting my component once, am I still doing it the wrong way? It is an input field, which after input has been received, and button pressed, component is unmounted, and input is translated to new rendered components? Thank you it is much appreciated. It's just I have gone through the docs numerous times, as well as redux, and numerous repos, and I feel I am headed in the right direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101742/discussion-between-razroo-chief-and-david-l-walsh).

Comment: It's not necessary to formally unmount the component. It's better to have a state variable corresponding to whether the input is shown. The render method of the parent component would contain the logic (an if statement or ternary) that determines whether to show it or not.